# When to use userEvent and fireEvent in react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

```
test("hover / unhover element", async () => {
  const DOM = render();

  userEvent.hover(DOM.getByTestId("tool"));

  expect(await DOM.findByText("showing tool")).toBeInTheDocument();

  userEvent.unhover(DOM.getByTestId("tool"));
  const tooltipDisappears = screen.queryByRole("tooltip");
  expect(tooltipDisappears).not.toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Currently am learning React Testing Library.
I'd like to test mouse interaction with an tooltip and i am not sure which one to use.which is more efficient?

Comment: Use whichever one works

Answer (score 1):

Within the React Testing Library community `userEvent` is preferred over `fireEvent`.

There is a [linter rule](https://github.com/testing-library/eslint-plugin-testing-library/blob/main/docs/rules/prefer-user-event.md) that automatically steers developers away from `fireEvent` and towards `userEvent`.

Kent C. Dodds, author of the library and authority figure in the community, explicitly instructs developers to use `userEvent` on [his blog](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library#not-using-testing-libraryuser-event).